# What does a question mark (?) mean in a Typescript import statement?

Tags: typescript

What does `?` mean in a Typescript `import` statement. The [typescript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import) and [javascript documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) make no reference to this syntax.

For example:

```js
import example from './scenes/example?scene';
```

is importing something from a local file `./scenes/example.tsx`.

What does `?scene` do here?

Original source of this example: https://motion-canvas.github.io/docs/quickstart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not part of standart.  `?` can be used to add custom query parameters to a module request. This can be used to modify the behavior of the loader or plugin associated with that module.

https://dev.to/lioness100/adding-url-search-parameters-to-imports-1kd8